# AngularJs ng-options for a nested JSON with a filter condition on the parent object

Tags: html, json, angularjs, filter

I have a JSON structure

```
$scope.table = [{ 'ContainerNo': 'EGSU9014188', 'ISO': '4510', 'Type': 'IMPORT-FCL', 'Status': 'YARD', 'Hold': 'CUSTOMS', 'BLBENo': 'NIL', 'IDOExpiry': '30-05-2015', 'Remarks': 'Not valid for any transaction', 'flag': true, 'TransList': [{ 'Values': '' }] },
            { 'ContainerNo': 'EMCU3886883', 'ISO': '2201', 'Type': 'IMPORT-FCL', 'Status': 'YARD', 'Hold': 'NIL', 'BLBENo': 'I/25493/2013', 'IDOExpiry': '30-05-2015', 'Remarks': 'Valid for DI', 'flag': false, 'TransList': [{ 'Values': 'DI' }] },
            { 'ContainerNo': 'CARU9997951', 'ISO': '4510', 'Type': 'IMPORT-FCL', 'Status': 'YARD', 'Hold': 'LINE', 'BLBENo': 'I/4523/2013', 'IDOExpiry': 'NIL', 'Remarks': 'Not valid for any transaction', 'flag': true, 'TransList': [{ 'Values': '' }] },
            { 'ContainerNo': 'EMCU1313835', 'ISO': '4200', 'Type': 'IMPORT-FCL', 'Status': 'DEPARTED', 'Hold': 'NIL', 'BLBENo': 'I/245893/2013', 'IDOExpiry': '30-05-2015', 'Remarks': 'Valid for RM/RE', 'flag': false, 'TransList': [{ 'Values': 'RM' },{ 'Values': 'RE' }] },
            { 'ContainerNo': 'GESU4333339', 'ISO': '4510', 'Type': 'IMPORT-FCL', 'Status': 'DEPARTED', 'Hold': 'LINE', 'BLBENo': 'I/305693/2013', 'IDOExpiry': '02-05-2015', 'Remarks': 'Not valid for RM,Valid for RE', 'flag': true, 'TransList': [{ 'Values': 'RE' }] },
            { 'ContainerNo': 'EGSU3024492', 'ISO': '2200', 'Type': 'EXPORT-FCL', 'Status': 'DEPARTED', 'Hold': 'N/A', 'BLBENo': 'N/A', 'IDOExpiry': 'N/A', 'Remarks': 'Valid for RE/RM', 'flag': false, 'TransList': [{ 'Values': 'RE' },{ 'Values': 'RM' }] },
            { 'ContainerNo': 'EGHU9076761', 'ISO': '4510', 'Type': 'EXPORT-FCL', 'Status': 'YARD', 'Hold': 'N/A', 'BLBENo': 'N/A', 'IDOExpiry': 'N/A', 'Remarks': 'Not valid for any transactions', 'flag': true, 'TransList': [{ 'Values': '' }] },
            { 'ContainerNo': 'FSCU6944115', 'ISO': '4510', 'Type': 'STORAGE-MTY', 'Status': 'YARD', 'Hold': 'N/A', 'BLBENo': 'N/A', 'IDOExpiry': 'N/A', 'Remarks': 'Valid for DM', 'flag': false, 'TransList': [{ 'Values': 'DM' }] },
            { 'ContainerNo': 'CLHU8682640', 'ISO': '45G1', 'Type': 'STORAGE-MTY', 'Status': 'DEPARTED', 'Hold': 'N/A', 'BLBENo': 'N/A', 'IDOExpiry': 'N/A', 'Remarks': 'Valid for RE/RM', 'flag': true, 'TransList': [{ 'Values': 'RE'},{ 'Values': 'RM' }] }
```

I want to display the TransList which has multiple values in a dropdown.

```
    <select  ng-model="transactionTypeselected" ng-options="col.TransList.Values for col in table | filter : { ContainerNo : selectedContainer.ContainerNo}" >
</select>
```

selectedcontainer is set in the previous dropdown

```
<select ng-options="col.ContainerNo for col in table | filter : IsCheckSelected " ng-model="selectedContainer">
                                            </select>
```

The selectedcontainer should list the TransList types , it's a cascading dropdown . Need help with

```
ng-options="col.TransList.Values for col in table | filter : { ContainerNo : selectedContainer.ContainerNo}
```

Either the `JSON` structure I have chosen can be changed or the `ng-options` condition

Comment: can you provide jsfiddle or plunker? What help you need?

Comment: I need the values RE RM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case `selectedContainer` already save all row, so you not need filter again, just get value from it like

```
<select ng-model="transactionTypeselected" ng-options="col.Values for col in selectedContainer.TransList">
```

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.table = [{
          'ContainerNo': 'EGSU9014188',
          'ISO': '4510',
          'Type': 'IMPORT-FCL',
          'Status': 'YARD',
          'Hold': 'CUSTOMS',
          'BLBENo': 'NIL',
          'IDOExpiry': '30-05-2015',
          'Remarks': 'Not valid for any transaction',
          'flag': true,
          'TransList': [{
            'Values': ''
          }]
        }, {
          'ContainerNo': 'EMCU3886883',
          'ISO': '2201',
          'Type': 'IMPORT-FCL',
          'Status': 'YARD',
          'Hold': 'NIL',
          'BLBENo': 'I/25493/2013',
          'IDOExpiry': '30-05-2015',
          'Remarks': 'Valid for DI',
          'flag': false,
          'TransList': [{
            'Values': 'DI'
          }]
        }, {
          'ContainerNo': 'CARU9997951',
          'ISO': '4510',
          'Type': 'IMPORT-FCL',
          'Status': 'YARD',
          'Hold': 'LINE',
          'BLBENo': 'I/4523/2013',
          'IDOExpiry': 'NIL',
          'Remarks': 'Not valid for any transaction',
          'flag': true,
          'TransList': [{
            'Values': ''
          }]
        }, {
          'ContainerNo': 'EMCU1313835',
          'ISO': '4200',
          'Type': 'IMPORT-FCL',
          'Status': 'DEPARTED',
          'Hold': 'NIL',
          'BLBENo': 'I/245893/2013',
          'IDOExpiry': '30-05-2015',
          'Remarks': 'Valid for RM/RE',
          'flag': false,
          'TransList': [{
            'Values': 'RM'
          }, {
            'Values': 'RE'
          }]
        }, {
          'ContainerNo': 'GESU4333339',
          'ISO': '4510',
          'Type': 'IMPORT-FCL',
          'Status': 'DEPARTED',
          'Hold': 'LINE',
          'BLBENo': 'I/305693/2013',
          'IDOExpiry': '02-05-2015',
          'Remarks': 'Not valid for RM,Valid for RE',
          'flag': true,
          'TransList': [{
            'Values': 'RE'
          }]
        }, {
          'ContainerNo': 'EGSU3024492',
          'ISO': '2200',
          'Type': 'EXPORT-FCL',
          'Status': 'DEPARTED',
          'Hold': 'N/A',
          'BLBENo': 'N/A',
          'IDOExpiry': 'N/A',
          'Remarks': 'Valid for RE/RM',
          'flag': false,
          'TransList': [{
            'Values': 'RE'
          }, {
            'Values': 'RM'
          }]
        }, {
          'ContainerNo': 'EGHU9076761',
          'ISO': '4510',
          'Type': 'EXPORT-FCL',
          'Status': 'YARD',
          'Hold': 'N/A',
          'BLBENo': 'N/A',
          'IDOExpiry': 'N/A',
          'Remarks': 'Not valid for any transactions',
          'flag': true,
          'TransList': [{
            'Values': ''
          }]
        }, {
          'ContainerNo': 'FSCU6944115',
          'ISO': '4510',
          'Type': 'STORAGE-MTY',
          'Status': 'YARD',
          'Hold': 'N/A',
          'BLBENo': 'N/A',
          'IDOExpiry': 'N/A',
          'Remarks': 'Valid for DM',
          'flag': false,
          'TransList': [{
            'Values': 'DM'
          }]
        }, {
          'ContainerNo': 'CLHU8682640',
          'ISO': '45G1',
          'Type': 'STORAGE-MTY',
          'Status': 'DEPARTED',
          'Hold': 'N/A',
          'BLBENo': 'N/A',
          'IDOExpiry': 'N/A',
          'Remarks': 'Valid for RE/RM',
          'flag': true,
          'TransList': [{
            'Values': 'RE'
          }, {
            'Values': 'RM'
          }]
        }];
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <select ng-options="col.ContainerNo for col in table | filter : IsCheckSelected " ng-model="selectedContainer">
  </select>
    <select ng-model="transactionTypeselected" ng-options="col.Values for col in selectedContainer.TransList">
  </select>
</div>
```

**UPDATE** for sample in comment.
After filtering *table* you whatever get array of row from table, not single row. So you can't get collection `TransList` directly, but you can write simple *filter* that return array selected fields, something like this:

```
.filter('mapArray', function() {
  return function(array, field) {
    if (!angular.isArray(array)) return array;

    return array.reduce(function(acc,el){
      return acc.concat(el[field.field]);
      },[])
  }
})
```

and use it like

```
<select ng-model="transactionTypeselected" ng-options="col.Values for col in (table | filter : { ContainerNo : selectedContainer.ContainerNo} | mapArray:{field :'TransList'})">
</select>
```

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .filter('mapArray', function() {
    return function(array, field) {
      if (!angular.isArray(array)) return array;
      
      return array.reduce(function(acc,el){
        return acc.concat(el[field.field]);
        },[])
    }
  })
  .controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.table = [{
      'ContainerNo': 'EGSU9014188',
      'ISO': '4510',
      'Type': 'IMPORT-FCL',
      'Status': 'YARD',
      'Hold': 'CUSTOMS',
      'BLBENo': 'NIL',
      'IDOExpiry': '30-05-2015',
      'Remarks': 'Not valid for any transaction',
      'flag': true,
      'TransList': [{
        'Values': ''
      }]
    }, {
      'ContainerNo': 'EMCU3886883',
      'ISO': '2201',
      'Type': 'IMPORT-FCL',
      'Status': 'YARD',
      'Hold': 'NIL',
      'BLBENo': 'I/25493/2013',
      'IDOExpiry': '30-05-2015',
      'Remarks': 'Valid for DI',
      'flag': false,
      'TransList': [{
        'Values': 'DI'
      }]
    }, {
      'ContainerNo': 'CARU9997951',
      'ISO': '4510',
      'Type': 'IMPORT-FCL',
      'Status': 'YARD',
      'Hold': 'LINE',
      'BLBENo': 'I/4523/2013',
      'IDOExpiry': 'NIL',
      'Remarks': 'Not valid for any transaction',
      'flag': true,
      'TransList': [{
        'Values': ''
      }]
    }, {
      'ContainerNo': 'EMCU1313835',
      'ISO': '4200',
      'Type': 'IMPORT-FCL',
      'Status': 'DEPARTED',
      'Hold': 'NIL',
      'BLBENo': 'I/245893/2013',
      'IDOExpiry': '30-05-2015',
      'Remarks': 'Valid for RM/RE',
      'flag': false,
      'TransList': [{
        'Values': 'RM'
      }, {
        'Values': 'RE'
      }]
    }, {
      'ContainerNo': 'GESU4333339',
      'ISO': '4510',
      'Type': 'IMPORT-FCL',
      'Status': 'DEPARTED',
      'Hold': 'LINE',
      'BLBENo': 'I/305693/2013',
      'IDOExpiry': '02-05-2015',
      'Remarks': 'Not valid for RM,Valid for RE',
      'flag': true,
      'TransList': [{
        'Values': 'RE'
      }]
    }, {
      'ContainerNo': 'EGSU3024492',
      'ISO': '2200',
      'Type': 'EXPORT-FCL',
      'Status': 'DEPARTED',
      'Hold': 'N/A',
      'BLBENo': 'N/A',
      'IDOExpiry': 'N/A',
      'Remarks': 'Valid for RE/RM',
      'flag': false,
      'TransList': [{
        'Values': 'RE'
      }, {
        'Values': 'RM'
      }]
    }, {
      'ContainerNo': 'EGHU9076761',
      'ISO': '4510',
      'Type': 'EXPORT-FCL',
      'Status': 'YARD',
      'Hold': 'N/A',
      'BLBENo': 'N/A',
      'IDOExpiry': 'N/A',
      'Remarks': 'Not valid for any transactions',
      'flag': true,
      'TransList': [{
        'Values': ''
      }]
    }, {
      'ContainerNo': 'FSCU6944115',
      'ISO': '4510',
      'Type': 'STORAGE-MTY',
      'Status': 'YARD',
      'Hold': 'N/A',
      'BLBENo': 'N/A',
      'IDOExpiry': 'N/A',
      'Remarks': 'Valid for DM',
      'flag': false,
      'TransList': [{
        'Values': 'DM'
      }]
    }, {
      'ContainerNo': 'CLHU8682640',
      'ISO': '45G1',
      'Type': 'STORAGE-MTY',
      'Status': 'DEPARTED',
      'Hold': 'N/A',
      'BLBENo': 'N/A',
      'IDOExpiry': 'N/A',
      'Remarks': 'Valid for RE/RM',
      'flag': true,
      'TransList': [{
        'Values': 'RE'
      }, {
        'Values': 'RM'
      }]
    }];
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <select ng-options="col.ContainerNo for col in table | filter : IsCheckSelected " ng-model="selectedContainer">
  </select>
  <select ng-model="transactionTypeselected" ng-options="col.Values for col in (table | filter : { ContainerNo : selectedContainer.ContainerNo} | mapArray:{field :'TransList'})">
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks :) , took a lil late to realize selectedcontainer should already have the list , but is there any solution for deeply nested list ?

Comment: @RameezAhmedSayad, can you explain what you mean? you can access to  any deeply. If you update your question with sample, possibly i can update my answer

Comment: For my question , your answer is the correct one , for my comment , if the `selectedContainer` is not present and `ng-options="col.TransList.Values for col in table | filter : { ContainerNo : 'XYZ'}` is the condition

Comment: first: in your sample `TransList` does not have property _Values_, because  _TransList_ is array